# Conversion fails although generic params are constrainted

Tags: generics, interface, constraints

Here I got a small example which causes the compliler to deliver a error of type:

"Cannot implicitly convert type 'ProvideValueOne' to 'ValueProviderType'".

In my opinion it is not possible to violate the types in any way, so why is this code not accepted?

enlightenment appreciated.

```
public interface IProvideValue
{
    int Value { get; }
}

public class ProvideValueOne : IProvideValue
{
    public int Value
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }
}

public class ProvideValueTwo : IProvideValue
{
    public int Value
    {
        get { return 2; }
    }
}

public class BaseEntity<ValueProviderType> where ValueProviderType : IProvideValue
{
    public ValueProviderType Provider
    {
        get{
            return new ProvideValueOne(); // doesnt´t compile
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my opinion it is not possible to violate the types in any way

Oh but it is:

```
var x = new BaseEntity<ProviderValueTwo>();
ProviderValueTwo y = x.Provider;
```

So C# is correct to flag this. Did you perchance mean the following?

```
public class BaseEntity<ValueProviderType>
    where ValueProviderType : IProvideValue, new()
{
    public ValueProviderType Provider
    {
        get{
            return new ValueProviderType();
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the added `new` constraint.

Comment: +1: The only other point I would add is the naming convention for generic type params.

Answer (score 0):

The BaseEntity class only expects the ValueProviderType to implement IProvideValue. It has no idea what class it is... if it is even a class (maybe it's a struct??).

What if you add a 'new()' constraint and instantiate an instance of 'ValueProviderType'?

```
    public class BaseEntity<ValueProviderType> where ValueProviderType : IProvideValue,new()
{
    public ValueProviderType Provider
    {
        get{
            return new ValueProviderType(); // doesnt´t compile
        }
    }
}
```